# Symfony2 load external AppKernel file inside application

Tags: symfony, external, symfony-http-client

I need to load an external AppKernel file inside my symfony application. This external AppKernel is responsible for handling requests. The problem is, It can't autoload the classes/bundles that the external application uses. Is there a way to use an external symfony 2 application inside another application?

This is what I tried so far:

```
    require_once '/path/to/external/AppKernel.php';

    $class = 'Namespace\AppKernel';
    $path = realpath(dirname('/path/to/external/AppKernel.php'));

    // I tried this, but this does not work...
    $loader = require_once $path . '/autoload.php';

     /**
     * @var HttpKernel $kernel
     */
    $kernel = new $class('dev', true);

    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
```

Steffen

**EDIT**

I've tried the following also, the Kernel is loaded correctly, but I get a 404 on every `valid` request. I think i'm somewhat closer, someone any tips?

```
// Get Class Loader
$loader = \ComposerAutoloaderInitea05f7b71e624f9c387fc10b8508d099::getLoader();

// Add src folder to fallback dirs
$loader->add(null, array(realpath($path . '/../src')));

/**
 * @var Kernel $kernel
 */
$kernel = new $class('prod', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

return $response;
```

Comment: I'd also like to know this, did you figure out how to instantiate another AppKernel within a Symfony installation?

Comment: @MelvinValster Here a link to provide you with some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324414/symfony-2-handle-a-kernel-request-from-another-app-inside-a-service/20338458#20338458