# Symfony 2 - Handle a Kernel request (from another app) inside a service

Tags: php, symfony, curl, request, kernel

First I would like to say I find Symfony2 an amazing framework, so I'm creating a RESTful API with it using FOSRestBundle etc. But I'm not aiming for supporting only one symfony2 application with the API, I need multiple other symfony2 applications to interact with the API. I could indeed do this with the use of cURL and just make plain http requests to the API, but because the API is always on the same server as all the other projects I would like to handle the API requests directly trough it's Kernel (so no cURL). This comes with an amazing speed boost ofcourse and also less use of resources.

So, to make this happen, I first thought about simply requiring the AppKernel from it's destination, like so:

```
require_once '/path/to/external/AppKernel.php';
```

Then I would create an instance of AppKernel and handle the "sub-request" in here. But then, I instantly got errors, saying some bundles could not be loaded etc. which is logical because I only required the AppKernel file, not it's dependencies. So I included the autoloader of the API project (/app/autoload.php), but this did not resolve the problems, I got errors related to redeclared classes/functions etc.

This would give something like this:

```
require_once '/path/to/external/AppKernel.php';
$class = 'Namespace\AppKernel';

// I tried this, but this does not work...
$loader = require_once $path . '/autoload.php';

/**
  * @var HttpKernel $kernel
  */
$kernel = new $class('dev', true);

// $request contains a custom Request object created with 'Request::create()'
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

return $response;
```

I think I'm doing it all wrong with trying to handle it trough the AppKernel, maybe someone knows a better way to make a call to a external Symfony2 project (without cURL).

I really hope somebody could help me out!

Steffen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working :) I checked the routing files, and saw that the request was missing a forward slash (/) infront of the request uri. That explained the 404 not found. So my working KernelRequestHandler implementation is now:

```
class KernelRequestHandler implements RequestHandlerInterface
{
    private static $kernel;

    /**
     * Get ApiKernel instance
     *
     * @param $class
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getKernel($class)
    {
        if (!self::$kernel) {
            self::$kernel = new $class('prod', true);
        }

        return self::$kernel;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param array $endpoints
     * @return mixed
     * @throws InvalidConfigurationException
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, array $endpoints)
    {
        require_once $endpoints['kernel']['path'];

        if (!isset($endpoints['kernel']['class'])) {
            throw new InvalidConfigurationException(sprintf("No class name found for instantiating kernel. Client: '%s'", $this->getName()));
        }

        $class = $endpoints['kernel']['class'];

        $path = realpath(dirname($endpoints['kernel']['path']));

        // Get Class Loader
        $loader = $_GLOBALS['loader'];

        // Add src folder to fallback dirs
        $loader->add(null, array(realpath($path . '/../src')));

        $class = '\ApiKernel';

        /**
         * @var Kernel $kernel
         */
        $kernel = $this->getKernel($class);

        $response = $kernel->handle($request);

        return $response->getContent();
    }
}
```

Ofcourse this is just a working example, I'm going to implement this strategy in a better way. Well, good look to the one looking for the same answer!

EDIT:

I think the best way is to have 2 autoloaders, one for the main sf2 application and one for the API in this case. This way the vendors of both projects get autoloaded.

Comment: Did you end up keeping this method of referencing the autoloader within your controller? [I have a need for this as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727263/use-composer-autoloader-from-within-a-controller-to-add-alternative-namespace-po), but [the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20338935/3334390) on your other question were very negative about this strategy, so I wanted to know if you found a better solution. How did you create two auto loaders BTW?

Comment: @ChadwickMeyer Hey I ended up with adding the `autoload.php` file of my other library to the `app/autoload.php` file in my symfony application. Does this help you?

Comment: not really :P I don't understand what the code is that you merged into one file. I need to modify the namespace dynamically in my controller AFTER I know certain data about the site. So I'm using the $GLOBALS['loader'] method ATM, but looking for other ideas. Cheers.