# Symfony2 - Composer class loader instance in controller

Tags: symfony, composer-php, autoloader

Is there a way to get the composer autoloader instance inside a Symfony2 Controller?

Comment: why would you want that?

Comment: You don't need it - unless you provide an explanation why you do in your question. :)

Comment: See this question (it's the reason why I need it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324414/symfony-2-handle-a-kernel-request-from-another-app-inside-a-service

Comment: Also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727263/use-composer-autoloader-from-within-a-controller-to-add-alternative-namespace-po) requires this ability when the path is dynamic and not known until after the controller finds what template the user is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - there is a way.

And assuming that you want to know how to actually get the loader then you can do this in your controller:

```
class MyController
    function myAction()
    {
        die(get_class($GLOBALS['loader'])); // Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
```

Should you do this?  Probably not.  In most cases you can tweak the loader in the app/autoload.php file.

Comment: @Cerad Can you elaborate what problems may exist with this method? In [my case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27727263/3334390) I don't know which template the site is using until after my controller finds this information, so I cannot do it in the `app/autoload.php`.

Comment: In general, anytime you need to use a global should result a red flag.

Comment: @Cerad I agree. So how can you access the loader in Symfony the "correct" way? Can you make it a global service somehow and inject it? If you **need** to add paths dynamically, how else are you "supposed" to do this, according to the Symfony best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Using the $GLOBALS did not work for me, but you can also get it like this:

```
$autoload_functions = spl_autoload_functions();
$loader = $autoload_functions[0][0];
```

this assumes that "autoload.php" has been required, AND that it is configured to prepend the composer classloader to other classloaders (the default).

NOTE: I am not saying this is good style.